# How to replace substring in string using pcre library?

Tags: c, regex, pcre

for example:

```
(test)rrr(/test) -> (ll)rrr(/ll)
regexp: ( (test)(.*?)(test) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Pcre does not provide a replace out of the shelf for the c API. but the C++ header provide one.
You can either use C++ or use this code as an inspiration.

You can also look at some source code using pcre such as the Python source code or Php to implements this missing feature